# How do I make several ImageViews scale based on the screen size without changing their position relative to each other?

Tags: android, kotlin, uiimageview, imageview

A part of an app I'm making in Kotlin in Android Studio contains a map with provinces. (See image) [Replication of map of the Netherlands](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yXw1k.png) All of the provinces are different ImageViews, because I need to be able to change their color individually.

The issue comes with smaller or thinner screens where some ImageViews go off-screen or are not aligned anymore. To prevent this, I would like to make the entirety of the map scalable based on the size of the screen. It's okay for the ImageViews to become quite a bit smaller to still be usable, but I have not been able to figure it out. There are also a button on top of a part of each ImageView, as you can see in the mess on the right of the image.

I have tried using the custom scalable dp (sdp) but, even though I was able to make the size of the ImageViews, I could not get it to be reliable enough, but most importantly, I could not get them to keep their position relative to each other. This is a very important part as otherwise the map would no longer be intact.

Comment: Did you try using constraint layout?

Comment: @PawanSinghHarariya I am using a constraint layout at the moment. My current version has the map staying intact but not becoming smaller when the screen size decreases and thus thinner or smaller screens don't display the full map.

Comment: Try setting `layout_width` and `layout_height` to `0dp` instead of `wrap_content`, and use `scaleType:fitXY` for your image views.

Comment: Can you show your xml?

Comment: @PawanSinghHarariya I changed the layout width/height and scaleType for the image views. This does make it scale, but it also stretches out the image in the process. On top of that, it becomes a lot harder to position the ImageViews in the way they need to be. So I can't make the map look the way it is supposed to.

Comment: @Moataz [Here is my xml file for the map](https://hastebin.skyra.pw/ehorapubir.htm)